# How to reduce firebase bundle size?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm building my app to deploy to production. And my client bundled code is split by libraries.

And I've noticed that firebase has produced a quite large chunk.

It's 667kb as you can see below:

[image]

This is how I'm importing it on my code:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/functions';
import 'firebase/storage';

// .env file in root folder
const config = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Is there a way to reduce it?

Webpack is always warning about this chunk size.

Comment: Looks like the team is making progress on a smaller build https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2241

Answer (score 11):

Bit late to the party, but one potential way to solve bundle size is dynamically importing firestore.

Turns out `firebase.firestore` is `undefined` if you haven't imported it into the module.
This means you can ensure it is only imported once and export an async function that will return the firestore instance.

```js
// firebase.js
export async function getFirestoreInstance() {
  if (!firebase.firestore) {
    await import('firebase/firestore');
  }

  return firebase.firestore();
}

// Other file that needs firestore
async function doSomething(){
  const firestore = await getFirestoreInstance();
  firestore.collection('do stuff')
}
```

I'm yet to test this in production, but it seems to work fine in development with React & NextJS. I will update once I do.

Update: Ran this in production for over a year now and faced zero problems. Firebase has since released V9 with support for both legacy (compatibility) and tree shakeable mode.

Comment: Wow! Worked like a charm! In ANGULAR and Typescript.

I tried the same logic with @Angular/Fire, but couldn't make it work(@Angular/Fire has a nice router guard and observables).
`
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

export async function getFirestoreStorageInstance() {
  if (!firebase.default.storage) {
    await import('firebase/storage');
  }
  return firebase.default.storage();
}
`

Answer (score 6):

There is an active issue on the firebase-js-sdk repository: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2241. At the moment there isn't so much that can be done.

If you don't need some features like realtime, you can use a lite version developed here but the API is still unstable: https://github.com/samuelgozi/firebase-firestore-lite

Someone also tried to improve the loading time by separating the firebase code into a separate bundle, lazy-loading it and executing it in a `WebWorker`: https://davidea.st/articles/firebase-bundle-size

In my experience, I wasn't able to do anything. I need real-time features from firestore and only lazy-loading the bundle helped a little to avoid showing a blank page, but my page still needed `firestore` to shown content obviously.

---

**UPDATE**

The bundle file sizes issue is now being tracked in: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/332

Comment: I think we are in the same situation. I also need those features. I feel that Firebase is more focused on mobile apps, rather than on web apps. And that size is not a problem for a mobile app. What do you think?

Comment: `firebase-js-sdk` is only for web, mobile apps have their own SDK. That being said, I do feel the web library receive less attention than the other platforms. The Node.js firestore library is already much better. In my experience in the last years, I always had issues with Firebase web even when I was using the Angular-compatible version.

Answer (score 5):

As of 2021, May. The Firebase team has released version 9 of the Firebase JS SDK now available in beta! Version 9 is **fully modular and tree shakable**

Learn more how to upgrade from version 8 to 9 [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade)

Comment: Good to know. Will check that out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am using firebase (app, auth, database) in a vue application. What I observed that for entrypoints, I don't need the firebase modules, just user state is needed to show/hide some relevant parts. However, firebase comes into picture on actions (for example).
I managed to reduce the entrypoint size by lazy loading the firebase service and making use of webpackChunkName as below.

```
src\store\user.js
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
        ...
  },
  actions: {
    LOGIN ({ commit, dispatch, rootState }, { payload }) {
      const { email, password } = payload
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "templates" */'@/services/firebase')
            .then(firebase => {
        firebase.login(email, password)
                .then(success => {
          if (success) {
            ...
          }
        })
      })
    },
  }
}
```

Before this approach

```
File                                                          Size                                   Gzipped

  dist\js\chunk-vendors.c70c4cf6.js                             624.69 KiB                             177.55 KiB
  dist\js\app.ccbb0255.js                                       12.17 KiB                              4.51 KiB
  dist\js\chunk-2d21aab9.6d5ea268.js                            1.74 KiB                               0.75 KiB
  dist\service-worker.js                                        1.04 KiB                               0.61 KiB
  dist\precache-manifest.dfe6c8710d17438b19417144e7fe3fdf.js    0.67 KiB                               0.33 KiB
  dist\js\chunk-2d0c08d4.242e678f.js                            0.49 KiB                               0.33 KiB
```

After lazyloading,

```
File                                                          Size                                   Gzipped

  dist\js\templates.513b1084.js                                 491.87 KiB                             128.23 KiB
  dist\js\chunk-vendors.5b33c361.js                             135.65 KiB                             48.76 KiB
  dist\js\app.357109e3.js                                       8.62 KiB                               3.64 KiB
  dist\js\chunk-2d21aab9.afa42bc6.js                            1.75 KiB                               0.75 KiB
  dist\service-worker.js                                        1.04 KiB                               0.60 KiB
  dist\precache-manifest.abfe3a14b7eef653a3ed134b55abc947.js    0.76 KiB                               0.35 KiB
  dist\js\chunk-2d0c08d4.242e678f.js                            0.49 KiB                               0.33 KiB
```

May be someone can point out to improve it further.