# Reducing Firebase SDK bundle size?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've used the new tree-shakeable version of Firebase SDK, which still seems to produce quite a large chunk, considering what I use it for.

I only use the Firestore part, and have actually moved all Firestore operations to the backend, the only thing I'm doing on the front end is initiating the Firebase app instance and starting a snapshot listener (due to the real-time ability), yet the bundle produced is still 275kb large.

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getFirestore, collection, doc, onSnapshot, query, where, orderBy } from 'firebase/firestore'

const documents = ref(null)
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp)
const ref = query(collection(db, 'documents'), where(`something`, '==', 'something'), orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'))

const unsub = onSnapshot(ref, (snap) => {
  let results = []

  snap.docs.forEach(el => {
    el.data().createdAt && results.push({ ...el.data(), id: el.id })
  })

  documents.value = results
}, err => {
  console.log(err.message)
  documents.value = null
})
```

Is there a way to reduce that size slightly, without sacrificing the real-time ability?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63872364/10527268